# Change the Starting and Ending tone of Google Speech in Android (Programmatically)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am developing voice app in android. i used google speech recognizer.I want to change the starting tone of google speech and as well as ending tone. I tried ,to add my mp3file but what happens is it just merged to default stating and ending tone. I want to remove the default starting tone ,ending tone and i want to add my mp3 file.

```
private void enableMediaPlayer() {
  MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  Resources res = null;
  float volume = prefs.getFloat(PreferenceConstants.BELL_VOLUME,          PreferenceConstants.DEFAULT_BELL_VOLUME);
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            R.raw.starttone);

    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.start();
   mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, 100);}

   private void onRecordAudioPermissionGranted() {
   final  Activity activity =ConsoleActivity.this;
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    });
     try {

        enableMediaPlayer();

        Speech.getInstance().startListening(progress,this);
    } catch (SpeechRecognitionNotAvailable exc) {

        Utils.showSpeechNotSupportedDialog(this);
    } catch (GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException exc) {
        Utils.showEnableGoogleVoiceTyping(this);
    }
}
```

I tried like above , but mp3 which i customized is merged to the default tone.Please help me to figure out this.Thanks in Advance!!!